# pgpool showing an extra node Node Name: Not_Set, Host Name: localhost

Tags: postgresql, high-availability, pool

I have a pgpool cluster with 3 nodes, but when I query the watchdog info, from every node, I have an extra node "Node Name" Not Set, and a "Total Nodes" Count of 4. from node 1 and 2.

Where the Localhost node comes from?
I already checked the configuration file, nowhere there is a "localhost" node configured.

Funny thing, from node 3, the output of pcp_watchdog_info is OK, there is no Node Name: localhost in third node.

Thank you for your valuable help.

```
#  pcp_watchdog_info -h localhost -U pgpool -p 9898 -v
Password:
Watchdog Cluster Information
Total Nodes          : 4
Remote Nodes         : 3
Quorum state         : QUORUM EXIST
Alive Remote Nodes   : 2
VIP up on local node : YES
Master Node Name     : 192.168.1.61:9999 Linux pg01
Master Host Name     : 192.168.1.61

Watchdog Node Information
Node Name      : 192.168.1.61:9999 Linux pg01
Host Name      : 192.168.1.61
Delegate IP    : 192.168.1.69
Pgpool port    : 9999
Watchdog port  : 9000
Node priority  : 2
Status         : 4
Status Name    : MASTER

Node Name      : Not_Set
Host Name      : localhost
Delegate IP    : Not_Set
Pgpool port    : 0
Watchdog port  : 0
Node priority  : 0
Status         : 0
Status Name    : DEAD

Node Name      : 192.168.1.65:9999 Linux pg02
Host Name      : 192.168.1.65
Delegate IP    : 192.168.1.69
Pgpool port    : 9999
Watchdog port  : 9000
Node priority  : 1
Status         : 7
Status Name    : STANDBY

Node Name      : 192.168.1.71:9999 Linux pg03
Host Name      : 192.168.1.71
Delegate IP    : 192.168.1.69
Pgpool port    : 9999
Watchdog port  : 9000
Node priority  : 3
Status         : 7
Status Name    : STANDBY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After further investigation, I noticed in my pgpool.conf file I had started other_pgpool_hostnameX, at 1, it must start at 0

```
#other_pgpool_hostname0 --> causes a Node Name: Not_set to appear.
other_pgpool_hostname1
other_pgpool_hostname2
```